# Modeling an SQLite on iOS

Tags: ios, sqlite

I'm thinking about making an iOS app but I can't seem to find a good solution for the DB.

Without entering too much into details, think that I need to store in my DB all the date/time a user will have to do a task.
All I know is the starting date/time, how many tasks the user will do and the time interval between tasks.

The easiest way to do this, of course, is to enter one record for each date/time the user will do a task.

This way I could face the insertion of thousands of records, since the user can choose to repeat the daily tasks up to 5 years.

Each time the user opens up the app, he will see the daily tasks, so I'll have to fetch it from the DB.

I thought about inserting just one record for each task, indicating the starting and ending date/time, but it's not possible because the first and last day might be different.

Example:

Users choose 4 tasks per day at 6h interval, starting at 10AM:

First day:

task1: 10 AM

task2: 4 PM

task3: 10 PM

From second day on:

task1: 4 AM

task2: 10 AM

task3: 4 PM

task4: 10 PM

Last day:

task1: 4 AM

task2: 10 AM

I hope I've been clear enough and that someone will have some good ideas.
Thanks.

Comment: `The easiest way to do this, of course, is to enter one record for each date/time the user will do a task.` -- Yep.

Comment: `but it's not possible because the first and last day might be different.` -- So?  Why is that a problem?

Comment: No, you don't store a record for every possible repetition of an event. a repeated event with no end has theoretically an infinite number of occurences. You store ONE copy of the event, then have some method of storing repeat rules for it, so you can trivially compute if the event occurs in a date/time range.

Comment: This question is probably better suited for programmers.stachexchange.com.

Comment: @MarcB This is exactly what I thought, but I can't come up with a good solution. Any idea for this case?

Comment: @RobertHarvey Because I don't know how to do it. I don't know how many events will exist in a day, so I thought about creating another table (in a to-many relationship with the first one) that will hold all the date/time records. But at the end this last table will hold one record for each date/time and I don't think this is the right way to do it.

Answer (score 1):

Based on the following assumptions: 1) A project may consist of 1 or more Task(s). 2) A user may have 1 or more Project(s). 3) A task cannot be assigned to more than 1 project. 4) A Project cannot be assigned to more than 1 user.

I would model this as follows:

[image]

By the way, in iOS coredata you don't deal with 'records' you deal with 'objects'.

Comment: Let's take out the user table (this will be a single user app for now). Change Project with Task and Task with Time. This way it will be (more or less) what I have to do. The problem is, that if the user have 4 tasks per day, every day, for 3 years, the Time table will end up holding about 4320 records and I'd rather find a way (if it exists) to write just one (or a little more) record(s) for each task. For now I'm using SQLite directly because I don't know CoreData yet. Do you think CoreData is better/faster than SQLite?

Comment: My point is that if you organize it like I did above it makes more sense. You want to "group" a set of tasks together and wrap them in a time constraint. I call that a "project". A project has a time constraint and may have a number of tasks to complete. If you just assign a bunch of tasks to a user then you will have the problem you outlined. I would add timeStart and timeEnd fields to the task entity as well.

Comment: Change project to calendar if you want. Either way, you need a way to group your tasks

Comment: Note, you need to think about what you plan to do with 'tasks' in your code. Most likely, you will be creating task objects and using them. If this is the case then create task objects in coredata. When you fetch from coredata, you are ready to rock and roll. Last thing you want to do is convert some overly simplified (demarshalled) version of an object into an object in ios if you don't have to. Coredata is an object model not a relational model. You deal with objects not records.

Comment: I'm sorry but I think I didn't understand you correctly. If you'd have to get the records (objects if you wish) for the second and last day in my example, how would you do it? Of course I need the logic, not the code.

Comment: Sorry, maybe I'm missing it... I would create a Project or Calendar or Day (whatever entity you want to use to group tasks). I would assign the tasks to the Day. When you want to get the tasks for the last day you would grab the Day representing the last day and then all the tasks associated with it (i.e the group). Please clarify your example if I'm missing your point. I don't know what 'last day' means in your example so it's hard to be more specific.

Comment: The idea of assigning the tasks to a day seems more logic to me, so thank you for pointing me that way. Still, the Day table (if we talk in DB terms), will hold a record for each day from the first to the last, and that could mean tens of thousands of records. Now if this is inevitable, I'm interested about the performances of both SQLite and CoreData. Which would be faster in writing let's say 20000 records and in fetching the record for the current day?